# How to get the count of the given word in a column? using postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSql, I am having a table like below,

[image]

I need to get output as count of the given word (test) in text_col like below table using ts_vector function,
Please give me some suggestion, Thanks !.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT filename, cardinality(string_to_array(text_col,'test'))-1 
FROM documents;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=56b641ef94da44ffe0149d308bbf9d23)

Comment: if I use word 'Test' the above solution is not working. @Saya

Comment: string in the db is case-sensitive. If you want insensitive solution, then use `lower` function to make it work, like `string_to_array(lower(text_col),lower('Test'))`

Answer (score 1):

Using tsvector is like (globally)

```
select * from ts_stat('select to_tsvector(text_col) from document_table')
where word='test';
```

where ndoc is number of rows (documents) and nentry number of occurrences of the word

Or by row

```
select file_name, text_col, to_tsvector(text_col), 
substring(to_tsvector(text_col)::text, '''test'':(\d+(,\d+)*)') positions_in_text,
length(regexp_replace(substring(to_tsvector(text_col)::text, '''test'':(\d+(,\d+)*)'), '[^,]', '', 'g'))+1 occurrences 
from document_table
where text_col @@ to_tsquery('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about counting spaces?

The following takes the length of the original string, calculates the length of the string removing the spaces and then sums 1

```
with first_sel as (
    select 'Ciao io sono Ugo' mytext union all
    select 'Ciao io non sono Ugo' 
)
select mytext, length(mytext) - length(replace(mytext, ' ','')) + 1 nr_words from first_sel;
```

result

```
        mytext        | nr_words
----------------------+----------
 Ciao io sono Ugo     |        4
 Ciao io non sono Ugo |        5
(2 rows)
```

If it's not only about spaces you can try removing the needed characters with [regex_replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)